# Como realizar operação matemática dentro da view em MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, view

Estou criando uma aplicação web MVC 5 para estudos e tenho uma dúvida: é possível realizar uma operação matemática na *view*?

Queria realizar a multiplicação da linha 16. Qual seria a solução?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.users.first_name_user) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.users.last_name_user)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product.name_product)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)
    </td>
    <td>
        R$ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product.price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity) * @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product.price) ******Preciso Realizar essa multiplicação****
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = item.id_order }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Details", new { id = item.id_order }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Excluir", "Delete", new { id = item.id_order })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

[image: Tabela com resultados]

Tentei usar o código dessa forma:

```
R$ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity * item.product.price)
```

Apresentou esse erro:

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Comment: Por que não monta o *model* já com esse campo calculado. È até o mais certo a fazer.

Comment: Hum, não tinha pensado no model. Ele veio montado automaticamente de um banco sql server. Eu alterando o model, causa algum impacto no meu banco?

Comment: Não, é o correto.

Comment: Você está usando ORM ???

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, tem uma semana que comecei a mexer em asp. Então desconheço ORM, mas vou pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal não é fazer processamento na *view*, então a solução correta é criar o modelo que já inclua o valor total calculado como um campo do *model* (pode ser uma *viewmodel* se não quiser fazer no modelo normal), e aí pode usar facilmente.

Se quiser a forma **incorreta**, mas funciona, pode fazer a conta antes e depois usar o resultado, algo assim:

```
@{
foreach (var item in Model) {
    var total = item.quantity * item.product.price;
    ...
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => total)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/CalculateView.cs).

Comment: Adicionei na model o cálculo que resolveu o problema

public decimal total { get { return quantity * product.price; } }

e na view  chamei o total